# push notification iphone error (moon aspn)

Tags: c#, asp.net, apple-push-notifications

I'm using the moon aspn library for sending push notifications in asp.net and c#. I'm encountering the following error: `Call to SSPI Failed`; in the inner exception i have: `Unknown error while processing the certificate; error code: -2147467259`.

here is my code:

```
private void SendQueueToapple(IEnumerable<NotificationPayload> queue)
{
    int i = 1000;
    foreach (var item in queue)
    {
        if (!_conected)
        {
            Connect(_host, NotificationPort, _certificates);
            var response = new byte[6];
    --> --> --> _apnsStream.BeginRead(response, 0, 6, ReadResponse, new MyAsyncInfo(response,    _apnsStream));<-- <-- <--
        } try {
            if (item.DeviceToken.Length == 64) //check lenght of device token, if its shorter or longer stop generating Payload.
            {
                item.PayloadId = i;
                byte[] payload = GeneratePayload(item);
                _apnsStream.Write(payload);
                Logger.Info("Notification successfully sent to APNS server for Device Toekn : " + item.DeviceToken);
                Thread.Sleep(1000); //Wait to get the response from apple.
            }
            else
                Logger.Error("Invalid device token length, possible simulator entry: " + item.DeviceToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("An error occurred on sending payload for device token {0} - {1}", item.DeviceToken, ex.Message);
            _conected = false;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a certificate related problem. You have to create .cer and .p12 files. Pay close attention to these files. You first generate the .cer and I'm not going into detail here. There's enough material available. The problem comes when generating the .p12 file.

In your mac, go to the Keychain Access. Select "My Certificates" from the left pane. There you will see a list of certificates. Select the certificate you generated for push notifications. Right click and export. Make sure you **DO NOT** expand the certificate perform this step on the private key. That's where thing starts to go wrong.